# Import a "|" delimited text file into MySQL DB using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to load a text file locally into a MySQL database using PHP. The data file looks like:

```
Device Name|DE:VI:CE:MAC:AD:DR:ES:SS|1376493754086|1376493754086
```

There are many lines of data formatted exactly as above.

I'm trying to load this data into a pre-established table like this:

```
$file = @fopen("LOCAL_data_file.txt","r");
    $values = '';

    while(!feof($file)) 
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password","my_db");
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Error connecting to my_db: " . mysqli_connect_error();

        }
        $buffer = fgets($file, 4096); 

        list($a,$b,$c,$d)=explode("|",$buffer);
        /*echo $a;
        echo $b; 
        echo $c;
        echo $d;*/
        $ins="INSERT INTO 'tablet3' (Name, Address, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES
           ($a,$b,$c,$d)";
        mysqli_query($con,$ins);
     }
```

The data gets read from the file fine, because If I decomment the echoes of the list variables, it echos all of the data in the table. If I don't run the insert query, the table gets created with proper columns of "Name | Address | StartTime | Endtime" but with the insert query, the code returns a table with null data. I simply cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First start by removing the quotes in `INSERT INTO 'tablet3'` and ADD some in `($a,$b,$c,$d)` and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: How about using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: You have three technologies here: a data format, PHP, and MySQL. Your problem should exist with only one of them. Figure out which one it is and get back to us!

Comment: If you just want to import a CSV file, you can try existing import tools like phpmyadmin/Navicat.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'll fix my quote problems, Fred, and figure out the answer to your question Lightness Races in Orbit. Barmar, I tried LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE before and couldn't figure out how to make that work, either. I'll give that another try if I can't get this figured out. Thanks!

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: Assuming it is a controlled query, they do not need to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: Marc, I know this is sloppy code and it's vulnerable to attack. I'm just a PHP/MySQL beginner and trying to use this data to learn how to do it. Once I start working on a "finished product", I will have it checked by a pro to make sure it's good to go. This code is for a research project at school, and I'm no CS/CE major, I'm just trying to figure it out by doing.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated it and this is the query I got to work

This is assuming the database structure of:

```
Name(varchar or text)    Address(varchar or text)    StartTime(int)    EndTime(int)
```

**Query:**

```
$ins="INSERT INTO `tablet3` (Name, Address, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES
           ('$a','$b',$c,$d)";
```

Take note of the quotes around $a and $b. Also the tick marks around tablet3.

P.S. You don't really need anything around a table name.

Comment: You are correct that I structured the DB with varchar/varchar/int/int. I made those changes and I get the following errors:

    Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Users/UserName/Sites/MYdb.php on line 52

NOTE: I get undefined offsets 3, 2, and 1.

    Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't assign requested     address in /Users/UserName/Sites/MYdb.php on line 40
Error connecting to my_db: Can't assign requested address
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /Users/UserName/Sites/MYdb.php on line 58

Comment: Try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. And try restarting your web server. I personally never had this error.

Comment: I tried localhost with no luck. I'll try rewriting something using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Your script worked perfectly with the added Query that I put. So that should not be the problem. The problem lies within the connection.

Comment: Well, I rewrote the PHP file using a LOAD DATA INFILE command and ended up with the desired result. I don't know why I couldn't figure out LOAD DATA INFILE when I tried it before, but it worked this time, so I'm happy. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, good. LOAD DATA INFILE is a life saver when it comes mysql. I had a CSV file with 2 million rows in it. Doing it by php would be outrageous.